# get rank of players' height in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

We are going to have the rank of height, but I got 0 for all players
I convert the feet and inches into cm first, and use the sample code teacher gave us. 
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION player_height_rank (firstname VARCHAR, lastname VARCHAR) RETURNS int AS $$ 

DECLARE
rank INTEGER:= 0;
offset INTEGER:= 0;
tempValue FLOAT:= NULL;
r record;
BEGIN

FOR r IN SELECT ((p.h_feet * 30.48) + (p.h_inches * 2.54)) AS height， p.firstname, p.lastname
FROM players p
ORDER BY ((p.h_feet * 30.48) + (p.h_inches * 2.54)) DESC, p.firstname, p.lastname


LOOP

    IF r.height = tempValue then
        offset := offset + 1;
    ELSE
        rank := rank + offset + 1;
        offset := 0;
        tempValue := r.height;
    END IF;

    IF r.firstname = $1 AND r.lastname = $2 THEN
        RETURN rank;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

-- not in DB
RETURN 0;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--select * from player_height_rank('Ming', 'Yao');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine for me if I correct two bugs:

1. One of your commas is not really a comma, but a “[fullwidth comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#In_other_languages)”, UNICODE code point FF0C, which causes a syntax error.
2. You have a variable name `offset`, which causes SQL syntax errors because it is a [reserved key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL. If you *really* need to use that name, you have to enclose it in double quotes (`"`) throughout, but it is better to choose a different name.
   The reason this causes a problem is that an assignment like `offset := offset + 1;` in PL/pgSQL is translated into an SQL statement like `SELECT offset + 1 INTO offset;`.

You can do the whole thing in a single SQL query, which is more efficient:

```
SELECT rank
FROM (SELECT firstname,
             lastname,
             rank() OVER (ORDER BY h_feet + 12 * h_inches)
      FROM players
     ) dummy
WHERE firstname = 'Ming'
   AND lastname = 'Yao';
```

Comment: Thanks very much. but we are suppose to write a function instead of a query. I tried to double check my comma and changed it, also rename the variable name, but still can't get the correct output. I always got 0 or 1.

Comment: Then the best thing for you is to edit the question and add sample data and a demonstration how it goes wrong, since it works for me.